# Как оптимизировать этот код по времени?Рекурсия, сумма двух чисел

Tags: c++, рекурсия, олимпиада

Заданы три числа: a, b, c. Необходимо выяснить, можно ли так переставить цифры в числах a и b, чтобы в сумме получилось c.

Входные данные
Входной файл INPUT.TXT содержит три целых числа: a, b, c (0 ≤ a, b, c < 109). Числа разделены пробелом.

Выходные данные
В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT следует вывести YES, если искомая перестановка цифр возможна, в противном случае необходимо вывести NO. При положительном ответе во второй строке следует вывести число x, получаемое перестановкой цифр числа a, и число y, получаемое перестановкой цифр числа b, сумма которых равна c. Числа x и y при выводе не должны содержать ведущих нулей. Числа в строке разделены пробелом. Если решений несколько, то следует вывести ту пару, в которой число x минимально.

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <string>
    #include <algorithm>
    using namespace std;
    void peres(vector <char> t, vector <int> &resa, int i, int c) {
        int j = 0;
        if (i == t.size()) {
            string kus;
            int g = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < t.size(); ++k) { kus += t[k]; }
            g = stoi(kus);
            if (g < c) {
                resa.push_back(g);
            }
        }
    
        for (int j = i; j < t.size(); ++j) {
            swap(t[i], t[j]);
            peres(t, resa, i + 1, c);
        }
    
    }
    void mperes(vector <char> t, vector <int> &resb, int i, int c) {
        int j = 0;
        if (i == t.size()) {
            string kus;
            int g = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < t.size(); ++k) { kus += t[k]; }
            g = stoi(kus);
            if (g < c) {
                resb.push_back(g);
            }
        }
    
        for (int j = i; j < t.size(); ++j) {
            swap(t[i], t[j]);
            mperes(t, resb, i + 1, c);
        }
    
    }
    
    int main() {
        vector <int> resb;
        vector <int> resa;
        vector <char> t;
        vector <char> r;
        int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, e = 10000000050, w = -1, z=0;
        cin >> a >> b >> c;
        string astr = to_string(a);
        string bstr = to_string(b);
        for (auto now : astr) {
            t.push_back(now);
        }
        for (auto meow : bstr) {
            r.push_back(meow);
        }
        peres(t, resa, 0, c);
        mperes(r, resb, 0, c);
        sort(resa.begin(), resa.end());
        
        for (int f = 0; f < resa.size(); ++f) {
            for (int p = 0; p < resb.size(); ++p) {
                if (resb[p] + resa[f] == c) {
                    if (resa[f] < e) {
                        e = resa[f];
                        w = resb[p];
                        z++; break;
                       
                    }
                    
                }
                
                }
            if (z != 0) { break; }
            }
        if (w != -1) {
            cout << "YES" << endl;
            cout << e << " " << w;
        }
        else {
            cout << "NO";
        }
            return 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Какое-то у вас решение запутанное...

Оптимизацию кода всегда надо начинать с оптимизации алгоритма :)

Мое решение использует одну перестановку, а потом просто проверяет, состоит ли разность из тех же цифр, что и второе число...

```
int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    string x = to_string(a);
    string y = to_string(b);
    sort(begin(x),end(x));
    sort(begin(y),end(y));
    do
    {
        a = stoi(x);
        if (a > c) break;
        string z = to_string(c-a);
        while(z.size() < y.size()) z += '0';
        sort(begin(z),end(z));
        if (z == y)
        {
            cout << "YES\n" << a << " " << c-a << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    } while(next_permutation(begin(x),end(x)));
    cout << "NO\n";
}
```

Comment: Можно ли решить задачу быстрее чем за факториал? Какой-то поиск от младших разрядов к старшим?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Вижу только замену `if (a >= c) continue;` на `if (a >= c) break;`... Кстати, сейчас внесу в ответ. Больше в глаза ничего не бросается...

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Можно добавить всякие проверки типа а можно ли вообще получить такое число (сумма двух минимальных вариантов не должна превышать третье число, двух максимальных быть меньше него... Но это все паллиатив. В конце концов, 9! — достаточно небольшое значение...

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy если генерировать перестановку не целиком а идти с конца, то можно отсечь будет, но на асимптотику это влиять не будет. Можно вместо факториала сделать O(2^len) где len - суммарная длина a и b. но это будет для таких значений даже хуже факториала. А идея простая - битовые маски что мы взяли на суффиксе. пересчёт ровно 10 операций. Возможно тут можно избавится от части масок, но я не думал ещё =)

Answer (score 1):

У Harry - как всегда одно из лучших решений!
Ну а у вас есть чем заняться. :)

1. Зачем вам 2 одинаковых функции `peres` и `mperes`? Функции созданы в том числе для того, чтобы избежать дублирования кода. Оставляете одну `peres` и меняете вызов:

```
int main() 
{
    ...
    peres(t, resa, 0, c);
    peres(r, resb, 0, c);
```

2. Незачем переводить объекты `string` в `vector<char>`. Это по-сути одно и то же. К  содержимому `string` можно обращаться по индексу, как к массиву

```
// вот это - лишнее
int main() 
{       
    vector <char> t;
    vector <char> r;

    string astr = to_string(a);
    string bstr = to_string(b);
    for (auto now : astr)
        t.push_back(now);
    for (auto meow : bstr) 
         r.push_back(meow);

// проще - так:
void peres(string t, vector<int> &resa, int i, int c)
int main() 
{       
    string astr = to_string(a);
    string bstr = to_string(b);
    
    peres(t, resa, 0, c);
    peres(r, resb, 0, c);
```

3. Требование об использовании рекурсии обязательное? И написание функций перестановок тоже? Если нет - воспользуйтесь функцией `next_permutation()` - она вам сгенерит все перестановки строки. Только сначала строку отсортируйте по возрастанию.

```
string astr = to_string(a);
sort( astr.begin(), astr.end() );
do
{
} while( next_permutation( astr.begin(), astr.end() );
```

4. Дальше вы генерите все перестановки обоих чисел и сохраняете в двух массивах `vector <int>`. От сохранения можно отказаться - проверять сразу в цикле. А проверять можно:

- перестановки с перестановками переводя их в `int`
- разницу между первым слагаемым и результатом со вторым числом
- совпадение символов в разнице со вторым слагаемым - как у Harry (т.к. допускаются все перестановки второго слагаемого то если совпадают символы, то и числа равны)
- можно просто проверять является ли строка перестановкой другой строки функцией `is_permutation()` - т.к. у вас строки максимум из 3 элементов - это будет работать ненамного дольше.

5. Далее у вас ошибка - проверяя сочетания вы выходите из циклов при нахождении первой пары, а по условию задачи - "Если решений несколько, то следует вывести ту пару, в которой число x минимально."

```
        for (int f = 0; f < resa.size(); ++f) 
        {
            for (int p = 0; p < resb.size(); ++p) 
                if (resb[p] + resa[f] == c and resa[f] < e)
                {
                        e = resa[f];
                        w = resb[p];
                        z++; 
                        break;
                }
            if (z != 0) { break; }
        }
```

Здесь вам нужно запомнить решение, а каждое найденное следующее решение сравнивать с запомненным и в запоминать то, где `x` меньше.

Comment: Спасибо. Я отсортировала массив resa, поэтому подумала, что при первом нахождении нужно выходить, нет? А с функциями я запуталась, потому что я принимала массив по ссылке, а в самой функции стоит массив resa, и только он у меня заполнялся почему-то. Поэтому решила забить

Comment: Решений может быть несколько. Поэтому выходить при первом найденном - неправильно. В самой функции ничего не стоит. То, что внутри функции - локальные переменные, они не связаны с предыдущим кодом. Что вы в них передадите при вызове, тому они и будут равны. Вы сами себя запутали, дав одинаковые имена. Поменяйте в объявлении функции имена на несвязанные с предыдущим кодом - возможно вам легче будет `void peres(vector<char> t, vector<int> &v, int i, int c)`